# react-testing-library include third party css in snapshot

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am loading third party css manually by injecting into `index.html`.
I created snapshot test for react component. It outputs only the dom that has been generated.

Is there any way to include the css classed used in component to be included in generated snapshot to determine if anything has been changed?

Or is there any other way to find out changes how many components are affected by changes in third party css changes?